# How to run puppet bolt command remotely on Azure Virtual Machine through powershell

Tags: azure, puppet, azure-virtual-machine, puppet-bolt

I'm trying to run below `puppet bolt command` for remote `Azure VM` through `powershell`.

```
bolt command run ipconfig --targets winrm://158.28.0.546 --no-ssl -user testuser123 -password test@84p
```

getting below error for above command in powershell

> Failed on 192.168.0.140:
>
> Timeout after 10 seconds connecting to 192.168.0.140
>
> Failed on 1 target: 192.168.0.140

How to resolve above issue

**Update 1:**

`WinRM` enabled on remote `Azure Virtual Machine`. Even `Firewall` is disabled on `Azure VM` for public networks.

[image]

After adding `DNS name` in `Azure Portal`, I'm getting error as below

> Failed to connect to
> https://testazurevm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:5986/wsman:
>
> No connection could be made because target machine actively refused
> it

Comment: How do you run this command? Run the command in the local machine or in the remote VM?

Comment: I'm trying to run above command from local machine.

Comment: Are you sure the WINRM is enabled in the VM?

Comment: yes, I have shared screenshot in update 1 of question.

Comment: Can you WINRM to the VM without bolt? And also you need to check if you open the WINRM port in the NSG rule.

Comment: After adding DNS name I got error as "No connection could be made because target machine actively refused it."

Comment: It seems you need to check the firewall inside the VM. You also need to confirm if the VM can connect only with the WINRM.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Seems to be an issue with firewall and winrm configuration in VM.

Comment: OK, I will add an answer to display the reason and maybe you can accept it.

Comment: I have followed article given in my answer for firewall and winrm creation. It worked.Your response helped me a lot in looking into the solution.

Comment: @Charles Xu, I'm tring to run powershell script with above bolt commands in C# .But it is returning zero.Could you please guide me on below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977355/powershell-invoke-returning-zero-in-c-sharp-for-bolt-command-run

Comment: Yeah, I will take a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, the error shows a timeout after trying to connect. Generally, it is because the port does not allow you to connect. And there should be two reasons as I know. One is that the firewall does not allow access from the port. Another is that the port does not be listened to.

For you, you can check if the firewall allows the WinRM port and if the WinRM is enabled in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed after following below steps as given in below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/cloud-partner-portal/virtual-machine/cpp-configure-winrm-after-vm-creation

1. Navigate to the blade **Virtual machines >  > Settings/Networking**.
2. Click on the **NSG** name to display its properties: Under **Settings**, select 
   **Inbound security rules** to display this blade.
3. Click **+Add** to create a new rule called WinRM_HTTPS for TCP port 5986.
4. Click **OK** when you are finished supplying values.

**Configure VM to enable WinRM:**

Download and copy below to remote machine. (Get these files from link provided.)

- ConfigureWinRM.ps1
- makecert.exe
- winrmconf.cmd

Run below command in remote vm.

```
ConfigureWinRM.ps1 <vm-domain-name>
```