# Unable to run remote powershell script which is located in remote Azure VM D: drive using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I tried with below script in local machine to run `remote powershell script` which is located in `remote azure vm`.

I'm able to connect to `azure remote vm` through `powershell pssession`, but `Invoke-Command` is not returning anything. Unable to run `remote powershell script`.

[image]

I tried as below aswell

[image]

But `-FilePath` trying to look into local machine `D:` drive instead of remote azure vm `D:` drive.

How to run remote azure vm powershell script which is located in remote azure vm `D:` drive

Comment: Please do not add code as images. Instead, edit the question and add the code as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the fault probably lies in your `GetRemoteAzureVMHstName.ps1` script.

make sure it's actually printing something.

Comment: My remote powershell script has bolt commands similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956833/how-to-run-puppet-bolt-command-remotely-on-azure-virtual-machine-through-powersh?noredirect=1#comment107890565_60956833 to get another remote vm hostname.

Answer (score 0):

My script is working fine now.

In `Invoke-Command`, for `-Command` I removed single quotes for script file path and it worked.

`Invoke-Command` should be as below

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Command { D:\User1\GetRemoteAzureVMHstName.ps1 }
```

instead of below

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -Command { 'D:\User1\GetRemoteAzureVMHstName.ps1' }
```